# Bug in System.Array.Sort() in Framework 3.5, 4.0, 4.5 and 4.5.1?

Tags: .net, arrays, sorting

It isn't sorting this simple string correctly, and I tested it to be happening in Microsoft Framework 3.5, 4.0, 4.5 and 4.5.1 RC...

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim strarray() As String = New String() _
        {"a-n|o1|2004/02/12|", _
         "an|n9|2004/02/09|", _
         "an|o2|2003/12/30|"}
    Array.Sort(strarray)
    Debug.Print(String.Join(vbNewLine, strarray))
End Sub
```

Output is:

```
an|n9|2004/02/09|
a-n|o1|2004/02/12|
an|o2|2003/12/30|
```

Which is wrong. The "a-n" string should not be BETWEEN the other two "an" strings. I also verified that this happens regardless of what the first letter is... so you can replace the first letters of each string with "b" or "t" instead of "a" and it does the same thing. But, if I trim some of the end off the strings, such as this...

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim strarray() As String = New String() _
        {"a-n|", _
         "an|", _
         "an|"}
    Array.Sort(strarray)
    Debug.Print(String.Join(vbNewLine, strarray))
End Sub
```

Then the output looks more correct, and it gives:

```
an|
an|
a-n|
```

Is there a more reliable method for sorting arrays of strings? This bug / behavior in Array.Sort damaged one of my databases.

Comment: what is your current culture?

Comment: why aren't you sorting in your db?

Comment: I haven't changed it from whatever its default is. But I checked System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString and it shows "en-US"??

Comment: I'm just using text files for this data. But it's a long enough file that I started to call it a database, but it's not a real db.

Comment: It isn't wrong, a dash is neutral for sort order and quicksort is not a stable sort.  You'll have to impose your own sort order by passing your own IComparer.  Like StringComparer.Ordinal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String sorting issue in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354966/string-sorting-issue-in-c-sharp)

Comment: possbile duplicate [What should these comparisons return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264495/what-should-these-comparisons-return/)

Answer (score 2):

This is no bug.

The default `Comparer(Of String)` (but not the default `EqualityComparer(Of String)`) uses a *culture-dependent* comparison. Different conventions might be used in different cultures. For example some cultures say an `Ö` comes before a `P` because some kind of `O` comes before `P` in the alphabet, while other cultures has the opposite, because `Ö` is a separate letter, unrelated to `O`, and `Ö` comes late in their alphabets (after `Z`).

Note that a `Ö` can be Unicode normalized in two ways, either as a single `System.Char` value, or as two `Char` values (an `O` followed by a combining `¨`).

Also in some cultures, two letters are regarded, in some cases, as one. For example in Hungarian culture (`"hu-HU"`), `cukor` comes *before* `csak` because `cs` is *one* letter in Hungarian and comes after `c` in the alphabet. Similarly, in Danish (`"da-DK"`), `odenseaner` comes *before* `aalborgenser` because `aa` has a special status there.

What is your culture?

When it comes to hyphens `-`, like in your questions, all cultures in .NET ignores this character when sorting, only taking it into consideration if the strings are otherwise identical. This explains the behavior you see: If you remove the `-` character from the string that has one, your three strings are still distinct. They are sorted as if the `-` were not there.

Like I said, this goes for all cultures (currently) in .NET, including the `InvariantCulture`.

If you want to use a sorting where the numerical value of each `Char` is used, and no culture, use (like suggested in a comment to your question):

```
Array.Sort(strarray, StringComparer.Ordinal)
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Specifically, these two lines:

```
  myComp = New MyStringComparer(CompareInfo.GetCompareInfo("en-US"),
             CompareOptions.StringSort)
  Array.Sort(myArr, myComp)
```

should show you how to get you the sort order you're expecting.